# Issue connecting with SQLAnywhere via Python: sqlanydb.OperationalError: Parse error: Cannot find .ini file

Tags: python, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I'm afraid this might is just an configuration issue but maybe also some issue with coding. However, I'm trying to connect with a database using Python and sqlanydb. SQLAnywhere is installed within /opt/sybase and Shell is sourcing the sa_config.sh file.

Connection with normal tools are working well: E.g. via

```
dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=mydemo"
```

However, when I try doing this in Python with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ctypes
import sqlanydb

def main(args):
    db1 = sqlanydb.connect( userid="DBA",
                            password="sql",
                            DataSourceName="mytest")
    db1.close
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

it's failing with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myfile.py", line 52, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./myfile.py", line 42, in main
    DataSourceName="mytest")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlanydb.py", line 461, in connect
    return Connection(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlanydb.py", line 510, in __init__
    self.handleerror(*error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlanydb.py", line 520, in handleerror
    eh(self, None, errorclass, errorvalue)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlanydb.py", line 342, in standardErrorHandler
    raise errorclass(errorvalue)
sqlanydb.OperationalError: Parse error: Cannot find .ini file
```

I had a look onto sources of sqlanydb but didn't find any reference to an .ini file looking for at this point. So what is the correct way of enabling the ASA16 to run with sqlanydb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the error you'll get if you have no `~/.odbc.ini` file. You are specifying "DataSourceName=mytest", which tells the SQL Anywhere ODBC driver to look in `~/.odbc.ini` for a DSN called mytest, but no .ini file was found.

Use the dbdsn utility to create the DSN in question.

*Full disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Will give it a try. Can this please be prompted prominent in documentation that odbc is needed if it doesn't look like?

Comment: When I call sqlanydb.connect(uid='dba', pwd='dba', eng='django'), I get MemoryError and I cannot figure out why